# Add option missing in FILE menu in vs2012 express for wp7 while adding a scheduled task

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

While trying to implement background agents for Windows phone as per msdn document, the procedure mentioned is:

> To create an app that uses Scheduled Tasks
>   In Visual Studio, create a new Windows Phone App  project. This template is in the Windows Phone category.
>   Next, add a Scheduled Task project to your solution. From the File menu, select Add->New Project…. In the Add New Project dialog, select Windows Phone Scheduled Task Agent. Leave the default name, ScheduledTaskAgent1, and click OK.

But I failed to find ADD option in FILE menu. :(

Please guide me in this regard. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
Try to  right click on solution in solution explorer and than Add->New Project